# How to check if a character is after another

Tags: python, string, function

lets say I have a string y ='rtgxpsa'
if the character 'x' is in the string it has to be followed by the character 'p' or 'z' for the function to return True, if it is followed by any other character it returns False.

I cant find any example for something specifically like this
but I did try this

```
def find(word)
for i in word:
      if i == 'x' and i+1 == 'p' or i+1 == 'z':
        return True 
      else:
        return False

print(def('rtgxpsa'))
```

Any help would be appreciated ! don't hesitate asking if you need more details !

Comment: `and i+1 == 'p'` This won't work.  You're treating `i` as an _index_, but it isn't that.

Comment: What if you have `'rtxgxps'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should look like this

```py
def find(word):
  for i, current_letter in enumerate(word):
    if current_letter == 'x' and (word[i+1] == 'p' or word[i+1]== 'z'):
      return True 
  return False

print(find('rtgxpsa'))
```

`enumerate(word)` returns a generator that has a tuple of the index and the current value

Despite that, your algorithm can be approached differently to be more concise

```py
def find(word):
    return "xp" in word or "xz" in word
```

Answer (score 4):

There is the `in` operator which can check for a string in a string. That way you can check for both character combinations at once.

```py
def find(word):
    return "xp" in word or "xz" in word
```

Comment: The drawback, if you have many possibilities to test, is the increasing complexity. `in` is O(n) so you have to read the string as many times as you have a new check, making it O(n*m).

Comment: @mozway: That's true. At the moment I don't worry about performance. There's no indication in OPs question that this needs to be done with hundreds of combinations.

Comment: Sure for two it's probably fine, but it's always good to be aware of it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex, this gives you a good compromise between flexibility and efficiency:

```
import re

if re.search(r'x[pz]', word):
    # do something
```

As a function:

```
def find(word):
    return bool(re.search(r'x[pz]', word))
```

Comment: Probably should refactor the code to be in the form of a function like OP has it, or at least include it as well

Comment: @Samathingamajig I was actually adding a function ;)